# Yii 1.1 saving model fails to write into database

Tags: php, database, yii

In my *actionCreate()*:

```
$model=new Search;

    if(isset($_POST['Search']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Search'];
        $model->save();
    }
```

It doesn't save anything into the database. The *$model->save()* returns with true, no error message when I try using *getErrors()*, also *$model->validate()* returns with true when I try to use it and *$model->save(false)* is the same output.

I have the following in the model's rules:

```
array('user_id, session_id, testcase_id, exec', 'safe', 'on'=>'search')
```

I also printed the *$model->attributes* after sending the form and it has the right values. The database table accepts the given values, I don't get SQL error when adding the values manually.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what's the value of your `$_POST['Search'];`

Comment: Did you try to remove the 'on'=>'search'  at array('user_id, session_id, testcase_id, exec', 'safe', 'on'=>'search') ?

Comment: The value of my $_POST['Search'] is the values I entered in the input form and when I print the $model->attributes out it gives me back the right values. I tried removing 'on'=>'search' but doesn't help.

Comment: Try to set safe (or give other rules) all model attributes,I suppose there are more than those we see at the post

Comment: maybe its your table structure, try converting your query to a string and manually query it on your dbms

Comment: There aren't more, only these, so all of them are set to safe. As I mentioned manually I can query it into the db so I'm not giving wrong attributes (like string into number field or stg).

Comment: I also created the model, controller and form via Gii, so it should have the right values in default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. The problem was that I named the model "search" and somehow it might have encountered with the search function. As I renamed it to "user_search" it immediatelly worked properly.